# Python + Google Sheet | How to Update specific cells

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, batch-updates

I'm learning how to use Google Sheet API and Python.

Firstly, I need to update specific cells in Google Sheet, not a range of cells.

I could use update_cell(), but each update will take up a Write Request, which is not optimal.

```
sheet_ELCSV.update_cell(str(x),1,OH_row_Side)
sheet_ELCSV.update_cell(str(x),str(PairA_Idx),str(OH_row_Executed))
sheet_ELCSV.update_cell(str(x+1),1,"Fee")
sheet_ELCSV.update_cell(str(x+1),11,str(Sum_Fee))
```

I read the developers guide on spreadsheets().values().update() and batchUpdate. If I'm not mistaken, they only take 1 write request.
But I don't get how to do specific cells update.

```
ssName = sheet_ELCSV.title + '!'
cell_range = 'A2,B2,D2,A3,K3'
 
values = (
    ('Sell','-2.17','27760.0476'),
    ('Fee', '-2.38285229')
)
value_range = {
    'majorDimension' : 'ROWS',
    'values': values
}
service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId = ssID,
    valueInputOption = 'USER_ENTERED',
    range = ssName + cell_range,
    body = value_range
).execute()
```

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spreadsheets.values.update` is a method used for updating single range.

A range can be a single cell in a sheet or a group of adjacent cells in a sheet.

Here are the example of valid ranges:

- **Sheet1!A1:B2** refers to the first two cells in the top two rows of Sheet1.
- **Sheet1!A:A** refers to all the cells in the first column of Sheet1.
- **Sheet1!1:2** refers to the all the cells in the first two rows of Sheet1.
- **Sheet1!A5:A** refers to all the cells of the first column of Sheet 1, from row 5 onward.
- **A1:B2** refers to the first two cells in the top two rows of the first visible sheet.
- **Sheet1** refers to all the cells in Sheet1.
- **Sheet1!A1** refers to the A1 cell of Sheet1

To update multiple ranges at once, you can use `batchUpdate()`:

Try this code below:

```
batch_update_values_request_body = {
    "valueInputOption": "RAW",
    "data": [
        {
            'range': 'Sheet1!A2',
            'values': [['Sell']]
        },
        {
            'range': 'Sheet1!B2',
            'values': [['-2.17']]
        },
        {
            'range': 'Sheet1!D2',
            'values': [['27760.0476']]
        },
        {
            'range': 'Sheet1!A3',
            'values': [['Fee']]
        },
        {
            'range': 'Sheet1!K3',
            'values': [['-2.38285229']]
        },
    ]
}
service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
   spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, 
   body=batch_update_values_request_body
).execute()
```

**Output:**
[image: Sample output]

### Reference:

[batchUpdate()](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

[A1 Notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#:%7E:text=A1%20notation,-Some%20API%20methods&text=For%20example%2C%20valid%20ranges%20are,top%20two%20rows%20of%20Sheet1.&text=row%205%20onward.-,A1%3AB2%20refers%20to%20the%20first%20two%20cells%20in%20the,of%20the%20first%20visible%20sheet.)

Comment: I see. This will take only a single write request?

Comment: @user2741620 - Yes